# How to get max matched output

Tags: mysql, select, drupal-7, relational-database

I have a table like this

[image]

Now my requirement is like below:-

I have to fetch all Content ID related to User Id-31. Here the matching content id are 225,178. I am able to retrieve this. Now I want to do the following:-

I want to get all user id whose Content ID matches with Content ID of 31 in Decreasing order. It means that if all content id matches then it will appear first otherwise  it will appear last. Here User ID 20 matches 2 times,User Id 19 matches 1, User ID 1 also matches 1 times.  So Result set will be User ID 20,19,1. Now I want to achieve this in Mysql as well as db_select in Drupal 7

Comment: do a favor for me . put your data here not as image (image can be broken in futur). and make your desired result and if possible do a fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT userid 
FROM tab
WHERE contentid IN (
     SELECT contentid FROM tab
     WHERE userid= 31
   )
   AND userid <> 31
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df190/5

Comment: U R Right. I was missing ORDER BY count(*) DESC;. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.